# Json vs File storage? How can i decide when is worth to use a persistant storage api like Azure/Google Storage vs a mysql database column?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring, azure

So im building a project and we have fairly large data. My averga json has a size of 20 Kb sometimes more sometimes less, but it doesnt fluctuate a lot.
The thing is im using Spring Boot + React with Microsoft Azure and to render some data i use innerHtml (react's dangerouslySetInnerHTML). My question is how can i calculate/decide when is worth to put the data in a json file in storage and send the link through rest compared to have it as an entity in mysql. Im not sure if im making myself clear but i'd appreciate some clarity. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is hard to answer without knowing exactly how all the pieces fit together frequency, etc.

Aside from the typical "test them and see what works" here are some thoughts to *maybe* help you make a choice.

- blob/table will be faster than DB. 100%. I get double digit ms responses from Azure storage almost always. You're talking about a roundtrip in < 100ms for most items.
- you cannot use a query type lookup - to use blob/table you'll need to know the exact URL, 2 keys (partition/row) or at least 1 key (partition) if you want to get more than a single record). This provides super fast access. If you're going to need SQL type lookups, stick with DB.
- Azure storage is way cheaper than DB
- You need a good storage strategy for Azure storage. How do you plan on purging, archiving, cleaning up, etc. There's no good way to say "all records from 2020" unless you also implement a tracking table. This is a good read on some patterns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns

I really like Azure storage when it's doable. It's cheaper and faster so often. With some tracking tables, it's workable in more scenarios.

Where it dies: reporting. It's hard to do reporting (for business and enterprise level expectations) with data in storage (unless you track elsewhere)

Hope that helps a bit.